# How to get desired html layout in small screens which is differ in large screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I implemented markup code and got desired layout in large screens, but on reducing size of screen to the phone level I need layout like image-3 and in big screen like laptops it should be like image-1. Image-1,Image-3 refer to single image that i have linked.

I am using Bootstrap-4, html-5

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h6>Image-1 in large screens like laptop</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 ">

      <div class=" card">
        <button class="bg-danger" style="padding: 15%; font-size: 15px">bigone</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card"><button class="bg-danger" style="padding: 10%; font-size: 15px">oneSmall</button></div>
      <div class="card"><button class="bg-danger" style="padding: 10%; font-size: 15px">oneSmall</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- In order to fulfil desired layoutin small screens, i implemented this-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h6>Image-2 after i made changes to get layout like Image-3,but in large screen it looks</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-12 ">
      <div class=" card">
        <button class="bg-dark" style="padding: 15%; font-size: 15px">bigone</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-6"><button class="bg-dark" style="padding: 10%; font-size: 15px">oneSmall</button></div>
        <div class="card col-6"><button class="bg-dark" style="padding: 10%; font-size: 15px">oneSmall</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h6>Image-3, like this i need to get in phone's screen, or smaller devices</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class=" card">
        <button class="bg-danger" style="padding: 15%; font-size: 15px">bigone</button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="card col-6"><button class="bg-danger" style="padding-right: 50%; padding-bottom: 10%; font-size: 15px; width: 100%">oneSmall</button></div>
    <div class="card col-6"><button class="bg-danger" style="padding-left: 50%; padding-bottom: 10%;font-size: 15px; width: 100%">oneSmall</button></div>


  </div>
</div>
```

[image: desired output]

Image that describes layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **responsive grid classes** to change the layout at the desired breakpoints.

For example, `col-12 col-md-8` means 8 columns wide on `md` and larger, and 12 columns wide on `md` and smaller:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class=" card">
        <button class="bg-danger" style="padding: 15%; font-size: 15px">bigone</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <button class="bg-danger h-100" style="padding-right: 50%; padding-bottom: 10%; font-size: 15px; width: 100%">oneSmall</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <button class="bg-danger h-100" style="padding-right: 50%; padding-bottom: 10%; font-size: 15px; width: 100%">oneSmall</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/eTGcVjgAWH

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. Hope can help you.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
      <div class="card">
        <button class="bg-danger" style="padding: 15%; font-size: 15px">bigone</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card"><button class="bg-dark" style="padding: 10%; font-size: 15px">oneSmall</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card"><button class="bg-dark" style="padding: 10%; font-size: 15px">oneSmall</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```